# Setting up a Python ViewServer for CouchDB

Tags: python, macos, couchdb

I am trying to get up to speed with CouchDB. As a relatively new user on Python, I am trying to set up a view-server so that I can pass on python functions to couchdb.design.ViewDefinitions function. As I understand, ViewDefinitions take javascript code to execute map/reduce function.

Here is what I struggle to understand - I am well aware that this might be a basic question. According to wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_server):

To register query servers with CouchDB, add a line for each server to local.ini. The basic syntax is:
'[query_servers] python=/usr/bin/couchpy'

How do I access local.ini file? I am an 10.6.8 Mac user. Thanks!

Update: Thank you Kxepal. It seems I was able to create the design/view on Futon in Python. Alternatively, I figured that python viewserver can be created as follows: 
curl -X PUT http://[localhost]/_config/query_servers/python '"/path/to/couchpy"'

However, I still cannot execute the python script. Running the view on Couch results in following:
'Error: An error occurred accessing the view no response'

I would appreciate if somebody can point in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know there OSX keeps CouchDB config files, but you always may setup Python query server through [Futon](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro.html#using-futon). On sidebar click Configuration, than "Add section" at the bottom of the page and fill the fields with same data as you planned to write into local.ini. As bonus, you don't need  restart CouchDB - configuration changes through HTTP API are applied instantly, but be sure that you'd specified correct values.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same "Error: An error occurred accessing the view no response" problem, and it turned out to be a bug in my python code.  Specifically, in the javascript implementation I had something like:

```
function (doc) {    
    emit(doc.somefield, doc);
}
```

I had converted this to:

```
def map(doc):
    yield doc.somefield, doc
```

However, this gave me the "no response" error you describe.

Changing it to the following fixed the problem.

```
def map(doc):
        yield doc['somefield'], doc
```