# Setting up a view server on a remote CouchDB host

Tags: couchdb

Background: I am writing an R view server for CouchDB.

To configure a CouchDB instance to use a view server, one can make an API call like so (as per earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456989/setting-up-a-python-viewserver-for-couchdb)):

```
curl -X PUT http://[localhost]/_config/query_servers/python '"/path/to/couchpy"'
```

In this case, the call to CouchDB on a local host is telling Couch the local path to the query server.  However, is there any way to 'install' a query server on a remote CouchDB host through an API call to Couch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is currently not possible.

You could run an external on a different host, hooking it up with a proxy handler, global handler or db handler (see https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene for how to set that up)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to assume as vanilla of a CouchDB instance as I can.  What if I added the script to a PUT as an attachment?  The script would then have a path on the remote file system and if that could be determined, the query_servers could be configured to point to that remote path?

Comment: no, query servers have no understanding of remote-ness. You’d be building your own indexer.